# What does the term " irrational functions" mean?

Tags: linear-algebra

*(This question is more inclined towards Linear Systems Theory but it involves linear algebra and Laplace Transforms, hence I am hoping that this page can give me some answers.)*

So, the problem is as follows. A small linear system's transfer function was obtained as ***e^-s*** (Laplace transform), ***s*** being the Laplace term. They say that the transfer function is an ***irrational function*** of ***s***. What does this mean?

Comment: It does seem that something was lost in translation.  The phrase "transcendental function" seems to make more sense, or else to state tht the transfer function is *not* a rational function of $s$.

Comment: A rational function is a function that is the quotient of two polynomials.  My guess is that irrational function means not rational, though I've not heard of function being called irrational.