# Find the 12th term of the sequence given by the rule $t_n=4n-2$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find the 12th term of the sequence given by the rule $t_n=4n-2$.
>
> Is the answer $44$, or $48$, or $50$, or $46$?

I am trying to help my daughter. Please help me. I am interested in learning how to do this myself. Her online schooling is not very good at teaching her what she needs. She has to just watch videos and read tons of descriptions. Thank you in advance!

Comment: the tn looks liek that the 4n is like that and then its just -2

Comment: Did you replace $n$ with 5 and simplify right hand side of expression because that's all you have to do to find the fifth term?

Comment: and I have another one that is that tn then =3 then (-1) then a n-1 that is small on the upper right side of the (-1). i only know how to put it out like this... tn=3(-1)n-1

Comment: I have no idea how to do this at all and neither does my daughter. It looks like a foreign language to me. I have not been in school in 23 years i feel so dumb founded.

Comment: Why are you suggesting 44,48,50, or 56?  Is it multiple choice?  You should simply plug in $n=5$ to get $T_n =4n-2=4*5-2=20-2=18$.

Comment: So the sequence is: 2,6,10,14,18,23,.... and the fifth term is 18.

Comment: oh my the first one is to the 12th term

Comment: sorry the second one is the fifth term.

Comment: I hate to be such a bother... but can you possibly explain to me what a 12th term is and what a 5th term is or what the difference is or how you know how to add subtract divide or multiply? I want to be able help my child understand, because at the present time I cannot help her at all. I Know basic mathematics and thats it.

Comment: This user is either trolling or copy paste answering old questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1486877/what-does-the-term-irrational-functions-mean/2864872#2864872

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $n$th term of the sequence is 
$$t_n=4 \cdot n-2.
$$
To compute the 12th term of the sequence, just plug in $12$ for $n$:
$$
t_{12} = 4 \cdot (12)-2 = 48-2=46.
$$

---

It sounds like your other sequence is
$$
t_n = 3 \cdot (-1)^{n-1},
$$
if I understood you correctly.
To get the 5th term of this sequence, replace $n$ by $5$:
$$
t_n = 3 \cdot (-1)^{5-1} = 3 \cdot (-1)^4 = 3.
$$

Comment: what does plug in mean see am I just illiterate?

Comment: Don't worry, that's ok. "Plug in" means replace $n$ with the number $12$ to get the 12th term in the sequence.

Comment: "Plug in" is a colloquialism for "Substitute the value of".

Comment: so when it says 5th term the n then becomes 5?

Comment: so the other one that I am trying to understand is like this tn=3(-1) the it has a little n-1 on the upper side of the ) of the -1. so like this tn=3(-1)n-1

Comment: If we aren't used to writing formulas, we might describe this sequence to someone using words, like this: "To get the first term in the sequence, you multiply the number 1 by 4 then subtract 2. To get the second term in the sequence, you multiply the number 2 by 4 and then subtract 2. To get the third term in the sequence, you multiply the number 3 by 4 then subtract 2. And so on." But that is very wordy. It's much more concise to just say "If $n$ is a positive whole number then the $n$th term of the sequence is $4 \cdot n -2$." Since I'm lazy, I like this concise version. Less writing for me.

Answer (score 2):

If chickens laid eggs according to that rule, when you have n chickens, you have (4n - 2) number of eggs. For 1 chicken thats 4x1-2=2 eggs, for two chickens, 4x2-2=6 eggs, for n chickens, (4n-2) eggs.

Comment: oh wow that simple... LOL

Comment: thank you ALL so much